# Cassandra driver freezing up when METRICS_SESSION_ENABLED is passed

Tags: cassandra, cloud-foundry

I am trying to enable session metrics for Cassandra...

```
List<String> session = properties.getMetrics().getSession();
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(session)) {
    builder.withStringList(DefaultDriverOption.METRICS_SESSION_ENABLED, session);
}
...
```

But when run on cloud foundry it seems to just freeze up after this line. This is using v4 of the Datastax driver.

If I remove this line then everything runs as expected. How do I enable this property without the application freezing?

Or is there a way to get a better idea what is causing the freezing? There isn't an error message or any additional context provided in the logs.

The setup is similar to what is seen here...

https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/54ef5364ec159980106ce05491cabdd6a79565c4/common/dao-api/src/main/java/org/thingsboard/server/dao/cassandra/CassandraDriverOptions.java#L153C28-L153C28

Answer (score 0):

Not an acceptable answer but a workaround. Get the Tracer before loading to avoid the lazy loading conflict

```java
    import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer meterRegistryBuilderCustomizer(
            ObjectProvider<Tracer> tracer,
            final ObjectProvider<MeterRegistry> meterRegistry) {
            tracer.getIfAvailable();
            return sessionBuilder ->
                sessionBuilder.withMetricRegistry(meterRegistry.getIfAvailable(() -> Metrics.globalRegistry));
                sessionBuilder.withMetricRegistry(
                    meterRegistry.getIfAvailable(()->Metrics.globalRegistry)
                );
        }
```

The important part here is `tracer.getIfAvailable();` which prevents the lazy loading of the Tracer.